# DDD & ORM where to put the relation

Tags: orm, domain-driven-design

Apologies if this question has been answered, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding to this matter.

So to simplify my question, lets say that I have 2 domains - shop and member. Member has User class and Shop has Item class. Upon creating a purchase, I need a way to store the item seller. Where should the relation be? How I shall implement the relation in the cleanest way possible? I'm brainstorming for some time right now and in every possible scenario there would be domain coupling. I'd be happy to get some hints and suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Between domains you wont have any tx support, which implies no relational integrity. If the question is how to connect `Shop.Item` with a `Member.User` as "seller" I would just add a property/field `Shop.Item.Seller` as a `UUID/Guid` and leave it to the application layer to "validate" the relationship and handle whenever the referenced `Seller` does not exist.